Elasticity of demand calculation yields unit elasticity at $0. What's wrong?
I was trying to solve $E_D=\dfrac{dQ}{dP}\cdot\dfrac{P}{Q}=-1$, assuming $Q\neq0$.
$$
\begin{align*}
P\ dQ&=-Q\ dP\\
\int P\ dQ&=-\int Q\ dP\\
\end{align*}
$$
Integration by parts yields:
$$
\begin{align*}
PQ-\int Q\ dP&=-\int Q\ dP\\
PQ&=0\\
P&=0
\end{align*}
$$
But this isn't right for many reasons. First, plugging $P=0$ into the original equation for $E_D$ yields 0 (since it's safe to assume $dQ\neq0$ and $dP\neq0$). Second, when there's unit elasticity, this should maximize revenue, but if $P=0$, this means revenue is 0.
What have I done wrong in these calculations?

Welcome to the site.  Are you assuming that elasticity of demand is constant at $-1$ over the whole demand curve, or just that it equals $-1$ at one point?  Presumably the former, otherwise the integration wouldn't make sense.

@AdamBailey I think that might be the reason why, although that doesn't explain why plugging in $P=0$ wouldn't make $E_D=-1$ (just purely from a math point of view, no microeconomics perspective). I was assuming the latter. What would happen if I assumed the former?

Rewrite, by separating variables:
$$
\frac{1}{Q} d Q= -\frac{1}{P} dP
$$
Integrating both parts gives:
$$
\ln(Q) = - \ln(P) + C = \ln(1/P) + C, \qquad C \in \mathbb{R}
$$
Taking exponents on both sides gives that there is  a $A  = e^C > 0$ such that:
$$
Q = -\frac{A}{P}
$$
Double check for correctness. We have $\frac{dQ}{dP} = -\frac{A}{P^2}$, so:
$$
\frac{dQ}{dP} \frac{P}{Q} = -\frac{A}{P^2}\frac{P}{-\frac{A}{P}} = -1.
$$

There is mistake already in the step 2. In this problem $Q(P)$ so you need to take integral wrt $P$ so the equations should look like;
$$\int (P dQ) dP=− \int (Q dP) dP$$

But can't I write the equations as $\int PQ'(P)\ dP=\int Q(P)\ dP$? This makes the integration variable with respect to P on both sides.
